# Read google chrome custom search engines programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, decode

Is there a file(s) I can read and decode to get the list of custom search engines?
People say you can copy/paste `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data` to copy your engines to another computer, but the file isn't in plantext, I'm not sure how to read it.

I'm referring to these:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

`Web Data` is a `.sqlite` file

`select * from keywords` gets the search engines. <s>Although chrome needs to be closed... otherwise the database is somehow locked and I can't query it (This is a big issue, if anyone knows how to solve it please comment)</s>

If it's saying the db is locked while chrome is open, simply copy/paste `Web Data` to a temp file before reading it